# Load CSS in header on different view with layout in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hi I am new to Laravel 4 and have a question about loading CSS/JS files using the blade template engine. I am using an overall layout which contains a nav bar for every page. My question is if i want to include different CSS or JS files in the header of that page how would i accomplish this, i am extending the header. Here is an example

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')

{{HTML::script('js/example.js')}}
{{HTML::style('css/example.css')}}

@stop
```

Obviously my content section starts in the body of the default layout, and when i view page source on this the  and  tags appear in the body. Does this matter?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Roughly 3 seconds after I posted this I figured it out, I guess thats the way learning goes.

Make a header section in the view and yield that in the header like so...

View:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('header')

{{HTML::script('js/example.js')}}
{{HTML::style('css/example.css')}}

@stop


@section('content')

// page stuff

@stop
```

layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @yield('header')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a side note, if you want to extend and add another script lets say. You can use `@parent`. Eg: `@section('scripts') @parent //extra script @stop`. http://laravel.com/docs/templates